# What is the difference between scaffolds generated with & without nifty in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
 I have added  'nifty-generators' to my gem file. 
then executed following : 
rails g nifty:layout
case -1 
rails g  nifty:scaffold Post title:string content:text
case -2 
rails g scaffold Blog title:string content:text
rake db:migrate
```

When we genrate a scaffold with "nifty:" ; it does not provide "set_post"  & "post_params" methods.  but the later case provides those "set_post" & "post_params" methods.

Do we have any specific reason/difference between these two commands ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

Go to the Troubleshooting and FAQs section in the above page. !